# How did Earth Wind and Fire beat Aku?

Tags: samurai-jack

In episode XII Jack and the gangsters, we learn of the Jewel of Neptune, a powerful item that is guarded by three elemental monsters (that I shall call Earth Wind and Fire).  The reason Aku has not taken the Jewel of Neptune was that he was defeated by E, W, and F (or at least that he was unable to beat them).  How is this possible?  The only things that can harm Aku are Rama's arrows, Odin's Trident, Ra's energy beams and Jack's sword.

Comment: Basically because White is a better singer, they have better guitarists, and overall their songwriting skills are top notch.

Comment: Aku had also been thwarted on previous attempts to steal the jewel by the Goddess of Water herself, so it seems that elemental forces can be added to the list of things that harm him.

Comment: But they lack the vocal stylings of Mako.  How could they beat that?

Comment: Whilst your postulate may hold merit, there have been other instances where elemental attacks did not harm Aku (he has never been shown to be weak to fire).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to answer this in canon is to draw from what we see in Season 5. When Season 5 opens, we find that Jack is without his sword and Aku has a sort of... ennui about the whole thing. He's not even aware that Jack is swordless because he's gotten tired of the fight.

Let's apply that here. From the [unofficial transcript](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=samurai-jack&episode=s01e12) (emphasis mine)

> Long before you was born or I was born or anybody was born the Neptune Jewel was kept inside this mountain, see? Legend has it, it was placed there by an ancient spirit who gave the jewel special powers to control all the waters of the world, see? Naturally, Aku wanted the jewel's power so evil could control the world, which it should.
>   But then, this no-good, goody two-shoes, good-for-nothing got in the way, see? I don't know how she did it, but she beat our boss.
>   And she summoned the forces of nature to guard it: Earth.
>   Wind.
>   And Fire.
>   And so Earth, Wind and Fire have guarded the jewel for centuries, see? Making it impossible for Aku to get his hands on it.
>   **And since the big boss himself couldn't close the deal it's been centuries since anybody's even thought about it.**

So we know that Aku was not beaten *by* the three forces, but *by whomever created or summoned them*. And likely she made it *just difficult enough* for Aku that he couldn't easily overcome it. As a result, Aku just gave up on it.

In other words, those three never beat Aku, nor were they impossible to defeat (Jack beats them pretty handily), they just made it not worth his time to keep trying. Which is generally what good security systems do.

Comment: You sir or madam have just won yourself a bounty.  A truly superb answer in my opinion.